# Liquibase :Getting error as "Expected encoding was 'UTF-8' but a BOM was detected for 'UTF-16LE'"

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

For the first time I'm implementing Liquibase (version 3.8.1) for my project with MSSQLServer as database.

im trying to setup baseline for the existing sql server db which contains number of tables, views, storedprocedures and functions.

I was sucessfully able to generateChangeLog for the tables.

As there are number of Storedprocedures,Views and functions what i did was, i have generated the SQL scripts from the MSSQLSERVER->Tasks->GenerateScripts and used this generated sql files in my Liquibase Changelog with sqlFile option as mentioned below,

while executing the above change log with liquibase update i'm getting the error "Unexpected error running Liquibase: Expected encoding was 'UTF-8' but a BOM was detected for 'UTF-16LE'"

I need quick assistance on resolving the above issue. please guide what am i doing wrong here.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">
  <changeSet id="1" author="bob">
    <sqlFile path ="dbo.GetClaimDetails.sql"/>
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Thanks,
Archana

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem Rather just converting each file to Utf-8 using notedpad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates that either the changelog.xml or your sqlFile has an unexpected encoding. My first guess is that it is the sql file.

There are several ways to check the encoding of a file. Since you mentioned SQL Server, I am going to assume you are on Windows rather than Linux. On Windows, I use Notepad++ for basic editing tasks. When you open a file in Notepad++, look at the bottom right corner of the screen - it will show the encoding of the file.